# Stroustrup's P:PP Chapter 4 Drill: Stuck

Tags: c++

I'm stuck on Stroustrup's P:PP Chapter 4 Drill, part 5. The problem asks me to write a program that consists of a while-loop that reads 2 doubles and terminates the program when the character | is entered. The program should  output both the doubles, tell you which is smaller and larger, and whether or not they're equal or almost equal. I took the definition for almost equal to be when the numbers are within 0.1 of each other. I also wrote the program so that it terminates when any non-double input is entered, instead of just |.

When I input 15.0 and 19.0, I'm still told that "The values are almost equal," instead of that 15.0 is smaller and 19.0 is larger. Curiously, if I input 19.0 and 15.0, it will tell me that the smaller value is 15, and the larger one is 19. If I input 15.0 and 15.0, it does tell me the values are now equal.

Basically, if x < y, and I input in the order "x y" I get "almost equal," but if I input "y x" I'm told that x is smaller and y is larger. Otherwise, error-free.

Any suggestions?

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double val1 = 0;
    double val2 = 0;
    cout << "Enter 2 values: \n";

    while (cin >> val1 >> val2) {

        if (val1 < val2) {
            cout << "The smaller value is " << val1 << " and the bigger value is " << val2 << '\n';
        }
        else if (val1 == val2) {
            cout << "Both values are equal.\n";
        }
        else if (val1 > val2) {
            cout << "The smaller value is " << val2 << " and the bigger value is " << val1 << '\n';
        }
        else (val1 - val2 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2 || val2 - val1 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2) {
            cout << "The values are almost equal.\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  As your code is right now it won't even compile.

Comment: `else (val1 - val2 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2 || val2 - val1 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2)` is not valid syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly write that, though. I'm a complete beginner to programming and this is my 2nd week. Would you have any tips on how to write it properly?

Comment: Write what?  You said the code works but it gives you a bad answer.  I am saying the code you posted doesn't even compile so we can't tell you why it doesn't work.  Do you actually have a working version of this code and is  it the same as what you posted here?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness - it compiles for me, and it is the exact same as I have it up there. I'm on VS2015 Community, if that matters at all. As for writing what, the incorrect syntax on the statement you quoted.

Comment: @JXX: you might want to check the `else (val1`... bit in your editor is really saying exactly that, as it shouldn't compile, and that you're not accidentally running a previously built version despite the compilation error; for example, change `"Enter 2 values:"` to `"Enter two values:"` and make sure you can see that prompt when it runs....

Comment: Maybe I'm using VS2015 incorrectly, but I changed the cout like you said, and I F5'ed it to debug - it's still running properly for me. I'll use the suggestions you gave me further below and see if that changes anything!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the order of your "if-else" conditions: it is important because as soon as one such condition is fulfilled, the other ones will no longer be even checked.

Comment: that is what the OP wants.  The code is broke and won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
else (val1 - val2 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2 || val2 - val1 <= 0.01 && val1 != val2) {
```

- should have the `else` replaced with `if`, so that - regardless of the earlier output, it tests this specific condition and may print the "almost equals" message
- needs the condition fixed: your logic would work if you compared the *absolute value* of `val1 - val2` to the `0.01` threshold (but as it is now, it's always `true`); [hint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)

To have the program only terminate when '|' is entered is a little tricky - you could wrap your currrent `while` loop in something like this:

```
do
{
    while (cin >> val1 >> val2) etc. as you have now...

} while (!cin.eof() && cin.clear() && cin.peek() != '|' && cin.ignore(1);
```

What that does is exit if you're at the end of the input, otherwise `clear` the stream error state, check the next character isn't a `'|'`, and if it's not `ignore` whatever garbage character broke the numeric parsing and loop back to try again at the following character.

Note though that if there was one good number then a garbage character, the good number will be thrown away and it will start looking for a sequence of two good numbers after any garbage characters are skipped.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, and I appreciate the link. Abs does seem like what I'm looking for, and that | termination does look like the solution that Stroustrup is looking for.

Comment: @JXX: you're welcome.  I'm a bit surprised by the '|' thing actually - seems a little complicated to ask beginners to do, but it's the kind of thing that people need to learn if they're going to use `istream`'s for parsing interactive (e.g. keyboard) input.  Cheers

Comment: @JXX I would suggest a one thing to have more readable code, and it also happens to make doing the comparisons a little easier (imo).

I would declare your two variables as `max` and `min`. Then read your first value into `max`, and your second value into `min`. Then check if `min > max`. if so, swap them.

Now you have two well named variables and have established invariant that after that `max >= min`